# Doctrine2 - double left join query issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I am using `Symfony v3.4 branch` with `Doctrine`.

I am having trouble translating SQL query to Doctrine ORM query.

I have 3 tables.

- Shop
- Firm
- User

User --> 1:1 --> Firm --> 1:1 --> Shop

(Symfony developer tool bar reports that associations in tables are made correctly).

I want to get `Shop` data that corresponds to cretain `User` in one query.

**My SQL, that get a result:**

```
SELECT *
FROM mp2_fos_user as u
LEFT JOIN mp2_firm AS f ON u.id = f.firmUserId
LEFT JOIN mp2_shop AS s ON f.id = s.shopFirmId
WHERE u.id = 1
```

**My Doctrine ORM query**

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('u, f, s')
->from('App:User', 'u')
->leftJoin('u.userFirm WITH u.id = f.firmUserId', 'f')
->leftJoin('f.firmShop WITH f.id = s.shopFirmId', 's')
->where('u.id = :user_id')
->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
->getQuery();
```

at the moment running the code results in an error

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected end of string, got 'u'`

What would be best practice for my issue?

Help would be much appreciated,
Thank you!

### UPDATE

tried:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('s.id')
->from('App:User', 'u')
->leftJoin('u.userFirm WITH f.firmUser = u', 'f')
->leftJoin('f.firmShop WITH s.shopFirm = f', 's')
->where('u.id = :user_id')
->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
->getQuery();
```

got `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 54: Error: Expected end of string, got 'f'`

Comment: If the `mp2_firm` entity has a relationship with the `mp2_fos_user` entity via the property `firmUser`, then try the WITH statement as `WITH f.firmUser = u`.  Same with idea with `firmShop`

Comment: @geoB thank you for suggestion. Sadly problem persists. I updated question to reflect that. Although error changed slightly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `WITH` clause if you have defined mapping in your entities, `WITH` clause is used when you want to join your entities with additional matching criteria

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\YourRelationShipNature(targetEntity="App\Entity\Firm", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $userFirm;
}

class Firm
{
    /**
     * @ORM\YourRelationShipNature(targetEntity="App\Entity\Shop", mappedBy="firm")
     */
    private $firmShop;
}


class Shop
{
    //.....
}
```

And then your could simple use properties to join your entites

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u, f, s')
    ->from('App:User', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u.userFirm', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('f.firmShop', 's')
    ->where('u.id = :user_id')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
    ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of something more along the lines of this (assuming the entity names are correct):

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u, f, s')
    ->from('App:User', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('App:UserFirm f WITH f.firmUser = u')
    ->leftJoin('App:FirmShop s WITH s.shopFirm = f')
    ->where('u.id = :user_id')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for ideas, but your example results in error.